# Java generics, explanation needed

Tags: java, generics

There are several simple test-case classes:

```
public interface ListCriteria<T> {
  // some stuff here
}

public class UserListCriteria implements ListCriteria<User> {
 // implementation
}

public interface Editor<T> {
  // sample method 1
  List<T> listObjectsTest1(ListCriteria<T> criteria);
  // sample method 2
  <L extends ListCriteria<T>> List<T> listObjectsTest2(L criteria);
}
```

And there is an implementation of `Editor` which Java thinks it does not provide necessary implementation for both sample methods:

```
public class UserEditor implements Editor<User> {

  @Override
  public List<User> listObjectsTest1(UserListCriteria criteria) {
    //
  }

  @Override
  public List<User> listObjectsTest2(UserListCriteria criteria) {
    //
  }
}
```

Both method implementations are wrong. The question is why. Especially for the latter method.
Sure I could do `interface Editor<T, L extends ListCriteria<T>>`, and that would solve the issue, but I don't want to, I want to understand why I can't use method-level generics here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you get have nothing to do with generics, because you implement the method with another type than the interface enforces.

The `Editor` interface defines

```
List<T> listObjectsTest1(ListCriteria<T> criteria);
```

Thus the `UserEditor` must implement in your case

```
public List<User> listObjectsTest1(ListCriteria<User> criteria) {
```

You should not mistake the parameter's type with the parameter's generic type. The `Editor` interface enforces a `ListCriteria` type. The `ListCriteria`'s generic type is `T` and `T` can be bound by a subclass, e.g `implements ListCriteria<User>`. That is what I mean when I say *"errors you get have nothing to do with generics"*.

I guess what you wanted was

```
public interface Editor<C, T extends ListCriteria<C>> {
    List<C> listObjectsTest1(T criteria);
}
```

and then the UserEditor can be implemented as

```
public class UserEditor implements Editor<User, UserListCriteria> {

   public List<User> listObjectsTest1(UserListCriteria criteria) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

> **why?  Especially for the latter method**

The second method in the `Editor` interface

```
  <L extends ListCriteria<T>> List<T> listObjectsTest2(L criteria);
```

does not mean that you can implement any type binding of `L`
The `UserEditor` must still implement

```
public <L extends ListCriteria<User>> List<User> listObjectsTest2(L criteria) {
    return null;
}
```

This method defines the generic type `L` that will be bound when a client invokes the method.
Thus you can invoke the method with any type that is a subtype of `ListCriteria<User>`.

Comment: Thanks, do I get you right saying that I can override the return type, but not the method arguments, and that I must hold on to exactly the same arg signatures even if `UserListCriteria` perfectly fits at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `listObjectsTest1(UserListCriteria criteria)` function of `UserEditor` is not overriding the function `listObjectsTest1(ListCriteria<T> criteria)` of `Editor<T>` interface because they have two different signature, i.e., essentially the argument type.
2. The same goes for `listObjectsTest2` which was declared in the interface: `<L extends ListCriteria<T>> List<T> listObjectsTest2(L criteria);` but you have declared it in the `UserEditor` class as: `List<User> listObjectsTest2(UserListCriteria criteria)`

So you will need to change the signature to:

```
class UserEditor implements Editor<User> {


    @Override
    public List<User> listObjectsTest1(ListCriteria<User> criteria) {

    }

    @Override
    public <L extends ListCriteria<User>> List<User> listObjectsTest2(L criteria) {

    }
}
```

Please read through [jls 8.4.8. Inheritance, Overriding, and Hiding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8) for more details.